# Understanding the functional equation $\left( \frac{2}{\pi} \right)^s \sin \left( \frac{\pi s}{2} \right) \Gamma(s)L(s)= L(1-s).$

Tags: number-theory, special-functions, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta, dirichlet-series

In the functional equation $L(s)$ is the Dirichlet Beta function which is defined as $L(s)= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{\chi(n)}{n^s}$ where $\chi$ is a Dirichlet character of period 4.

Now I know that this $L(s)$ is an entire function of s, and all the terms on left of the functional equation are entire except for the $\Gamma(s)$ which has poles at $s=0,-1,-2, \ldots$.

For $s=-2n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{0\}$, $\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)$ has simple zero and so there is not much of problem. I am having trouble understanding what happens when s is odd negative integer.

My guess is that $L$ function has zeros at negative odd integers. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: You guess right. Since the product is entire, each pole of $\Gamma$ has to be cancelled by a zero of one of the other factors.

Comment: @DanielFischer I am looking for a reference for this fact or any Idea how can I derive this. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: Which fact precisely? The functional equation, or that the functional equation implies the trivial zeros of $L$? The latter needs just a little knowledge of complex analysis. The former is proved in many books on (analytic) number theory.

Comment: The fact that $L$ function has zeroes at the negative odd integers, preferably a proof of this without using the functional equation. Yes, I am familiar with higher level complex analysis.

Comment: I'm not sure if there's a decent way to prove it without the functional equation. With the functional equation it's easy. $\frac{L(1-s)}{\Gamma(s)}$ is entire and has zeros (at least) at all non-positive integers, hence the same holds for $(2/\pi)^s \sin \bigl(\frac{\pi s}{2}\bigr)\cdot L(s)$. The first factor has no zeros at all, the sine factor doesn't vanish at odd integers, hence $L(s)$ must vanish at negative odd integers.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks for this idea. I basically wanted to show this instead of taking it beforehand and this argument works perfectly fine. If we have this equation say in some smaller domain then after using analytic continuation, your argument will easily show that the negative odd integers are zeros of $L$ function. Right?

Comment: Right, by the identity theorem we only need to know both sides of the equation are equal on some set that has an accumulation point, then it follows both sides are equal as meromorphic functions (and since one side is an entire holomorphic function, actually both are) on all of $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks a lot!